# Вытаскивание текста из тэгов регуляркой

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть текстовый файл:

```
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq><sq>
          fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
```

Мне нужен массив со всеми текстами между тэгами <sq>

Делаю так:

```
preg_match("#<sq>(.*)</sq>#si", $filecontent, $out);
```

В итоге на вывод получаю:
$out[0]:

```
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq><sq>
          fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
```

$out[1]:

```
    fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq><sq>
          fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg</sq>
    <sq>fgafdsg
```

Дальше массив пустой. В чем ошибка, подскажите, пожалуйста. Раньше с этим проблем не было. XML Parser-ы не предлагайте.

Comment: Не предлагаем. Считайте, что [задача не решаема](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте модификатор **U**, который поубавит регулярке жадности.
Вот так:

```
preg_match("#<sq>(.*)</sq>#Usi", $filecontent, $out);
```

а для того, чтобы выдернуть все тексты - используйте

```
preg_match_all("#<sq>(.*)</sq>#Usi", $filecontent, $out);
```